# Assigning IP of one machine to another Linux machine without downtime

Tags: linux, ip

I have machine which has an IP address. I am working on upgrading our services and we are booting one more VM. Once we validate the new vm we want to assign the same IP as old machine and kill old vm. We can only assign this ip if validation is right.This has to happen without downtime. Can some one suggest how to do this ? 
VM1: Docker Swarm
VM2: K8S

Comment: Define 'downtime'?  Having zero downtime isn't possible, but with the right automation you could get it down to 1-2 seconds or something. Though how you do that completely depends on your specific environment.

Comment: What kind of service is it? If it's HTTP based, you can also do an instant switch by proxying.

Comment: @Halfgaar Can you help me with more information on how we can have instant switch with Proxying ?

Answer (score 0):

If your network card is eth0, try:

`sudo ip addr add 1.2.3.4/24 dev eth0`

to add the old IP 1.2.3.4 to the new server, although it will interrupt tcp connections because the new server is not aware of them.

Also this is not persistent across reboots and failure to remove the ip or connection from the original system will cause an ip address conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with zero downtime. The first interface needs to be off the network before the new one comes up. When an IP is added to a network interface it sends an arp request to look for another interface with the same IP. If it gets a response it will throw an error.

Personally if we're only talking two servers I'd have two windows open and script the commands so that you could bring one down and then immediately switch to the other window and bring the other up. You'll need to keep a few things in mind here though:

1) You'll need to have a way to stay connected when the IP's change, like have another IP up so that you can stay on ssh while you're switching over or do it old-school from a physical console.

2) You will probably have to have all application services down during the switchover or the application's client will lose it's connection and possibly lose transaction data, unless you have some sort of high availability solution like a load balancer in front of the server. Not terribly important if it's a static web server, but if your client is submitting transaction data to middle-ware or a database that would be no bueno.

3) If you are running applications that depend on timestamped data, make sure both servers' clocks are in sync or your DBA will pitch a fit when he sees his transaction timestamps are off by a few seconds!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a mechanism in which VM1 interface can be made down and we can apply the ip to other VM ?

Comment: Not natively. You'll just have to type a command on one server then type a command in the other. Having a proxy or load balancer in front of both servers would be ideal, then you can just redirect traffic from one to the other. Without that you're limited to typing commands (or scripting them).

Answer (score 0):

The following may be an alternative to your idea of retaining the same IP, and assumes it's based on HTTP.

You can set up a new server, mimic the configuration and deploy the app to it. You can test is by adjusting your `/etc/hosts` (or OS dependent equivalent) and fiddle with it until everything works.

Then you can define a `proxy_pass` (nginx) or `ProxyPass` (Apache) in your original application's web config (read about proxies first, there are caveats). Once you reload the webserver, the app will instantly run on the new server. You can then change your DNS record, and people will slowly migrate away from using the proxied version to the new version.

I've migrated many webapps without a single lost request this way.